# Quartz scheduling thousands of new jobs

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

If we repeatedly schedule jobs, the scheduler thread seems to be woken up continually.
So it keeps running it's "find jobs" query, which is expensive.
We have seen this query running many times per second.

All the jobs we're adding will run in the future, e.g. 7 days from now.
So we don't need the scheduler thread to keep waking up.

I dug into the code and found QuartzScheduler.scheduleJob calls notifySchedulerThread
This uses a boolean signalOnSchedulingChange to determine whether to actually wake up
I can't see a way to set this boolean though

What's the recommended approach here, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to this
You can set the signalOnSchedulingChange flag to false by using a custom subclass of StdSchedulerFactory
e.g.

```
    /**
     * Custom StdSchedulerFactory
     *
     * Sets signalOnSchedulingChange to false so the SchedulerThread does not wake on every scheduleJob
     */
    public class CustomStdSchedulerFactory extends StdSchedulerFactory {

        private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomStdSchedulerFactory.class);

        @Override
        protected Scheduler instantiate(QuartzSchedulerResources rsrcs, QuartzScheduler qs) {

            LOG.info("setting signalOnSchedulingChange to false");
            qs.setSignalOnSchedulingChange(false);

            return super.instantiate(rsrcs, qs);
        }
    }
```